# In Pathfinder, is ceasing to concentrate a free action, immediate action or not an action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, actions, concentration

While it seems to be no real difference between those action types, for this action, there really is. If that is considered a free action, i can only do it during my own turn, otherwise i can drop concentration outside my turn, do as a part of another action or just do it no matter what circumstance i'm in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Cease concentration on a spell" is listed as a free action in the [Actions in Combat table](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#actions-in-combat). As you're aware, this means that you can only do it on your turn.

Comment: You are right. I didn't see it there. (I guess there's a workaround for that, but that's another thing).

Comment: It may be worth noting that some free actions are allowed off of your turn, and a GM could easily allow this to do the same if it helps the narrative/makes more sense.

Comment: @Ifusaso Isn't that only true for talking?

Comment: "[Attack of Opportunity  Basic  Free action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Actions-In-Combat)" They're definitely a minority, but others exist.